# MySQL: Selecting available vehicles that are not reserved

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have the following two records in the `reservation` table of a MySQL database.

[image: records]

When I use this query to get the vehicles that are available, it seems to give me every vehicle instead of just the ones not in the reservation table between the specified dates.

this is the query:

```
SELECT v.id, v.brand, v.type, v.description, v.airco, v.seats, v.hourly_rent 
FROM vehicle as v 
WHERE v.id 
NOT IN(
  (SELECT v.id 
  FROM vehicle as v 
  LEFT JOIN reservation as r on r.`vehicle_id` = v.id 
  WHERE r.status_id in(3,4,5) 
  AND (
    (
      ('2014-01-01' >= r.startdate AND '2014-01-03' <= r.enddate )
      OR
      ('2014-01-01' <= r.startdate AND '2014-01-03' >= r.enddate ) 
    ) 
    OR
    (
      ('2014-01-01' >= r.startdate AND '2014-01-01' <= r.enddate)
      OR
      ('2014-01-03' >= r.startdate AND '2014-01-03' <= r.enddate)
    )
  )
  GROUP BY v.id
  )
)
```

And when I use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM reservation as r
WHERE (
  (
    ('2014-01-01' >= r.startdate AND '2014-01-03' <= r.enddate )
    OR
    ('2014-01-01' <= r.startdate AND '2014-01-03' >= r.enddate ) 
  ) 
  OR
  (
    ('2014-01-01' >= r.startdate AND '2014-01-01' <= r.enddate)
    OR
    ('2014-01-03' >= r.startdate AND '2014-01-03' <= r.enddate)
  )
)
```

To get the reservations only, I get 1 record as u can see in the picture.

[image]
[image]

What could be wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Is this mysql or sql server it can not be both?!

Comment: Can we see the table structure for Vehicle and reservations?

Comment: I have edited my post with the table structure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This -

```
SELECT v.id, v.brand, v.type, v.description, v.airco, v.seats, v.hourly_rent
FROM vehicle AS v
LEFT JOIN reservation AS r
  ON v.id = r.vehicle_id
    AND r.startdate <= '2014-01-03'
    AND r.enddate >= '2014-01-01'
WHERE r.id IS NULL;
```

Or with your status entries

```
SELECT v.id, v.brand, v.type, v.description, v.airco, v.seats, v.hourly_rent
FROM vehicle AS v
LEFT JOIN reservation AS r
  ON v.id = r.vehicle_id
    AND r.startdate <= '2014-01-03'
    AND r.enddate >= '2014-01-01'
    AND r.status NOT IN (3,4,5)
WHERE r.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Why WHERE r.id IS NULL?

Comment: @xd6_ because the left join is to vehicles with reservations in the time period. Hence, no reservation means no join, no join means those values are NULL

Comment: Is this fully covered for the vehicles? i mean like.. no chance I get a vehicle that is reserved already? cause it seems to give me the right vehicles now.. and could you modify it to also check the status like I have now?

Comment: @Reshad - this finds vehicles with no record in the reservations table with an entry (any status) that would be overlapping If, for instance there was a reservation record with a status of 1 - Do you want that vehicle shown or not shown?

Comment: I have 5 status records. If a reservation has status 3, 4 or 5 the vehicle can be shown. else not shown. I have tried your modified answer but unfortunately I get all the records again :S

Comment: @Reshad - If status 3,4,5 can be shown, then use `NOT IN` in the `ON` clause. If those statuses cannot be shown, then use `IN`

Comment: @AgRizzo your answer is the best match for me ( if there is no leak in the query ) it works and its the best query I guess :) marking it as solution

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table structure it's harder to assume however this is my crack.
Just look where the V.id not exeists int the reservation table.

```
SELECT 
    v.id, 
    v.brand, 
    v.type, 
    v.description, 
    v.airco, 
    v.seats,
    v.hourly_rent 
FROM vehicle as v 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM reservation as r
            WHERE r.vehicle_id = v.id 
            AND  r.status_id NOT IN (3,4,5)
            AND(
           (
             ('2014-01-01' >= r.startdate AND '2014-01-03' <= r.enddate )
            OR
              ('2014-01-01' <= r.startdate AND '2014-01-03' >= r.enddate ) 
                        ) 
            OR
              (
               ('2014-01-01' >= r.startdate AND '2014-01-01' <= r.enddate)
            OR
              ('2014-01-03' >= r.startdate AND '2014-01-03' <= r.enddate)
               )
            ) 
        )
GROUP BY v.id))
```

Comment: This one does;t work because it can't find the r.startdate and enddate in the where clause

Comment: DV explanation possible?